# How to collapse page index in Evince

Tags: gnome, evince, elementary

I have a PDF file that contains thousands of page. How do I collapse the index from the file so I could only see the main topic **all at once**.
For example, from the image below I only want to see **Preface** without the subtopic.

[image: index]

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking but why don't you try clicking on the down arrow next to "Preface"?

Comment: I have updated the question. This PDF have 3000+ pages. Doing it manually will take time. I want to do this autamatically all at once. In Foxit Reader for Windwos there's an option for collapse all. I'm looking for this kind of feature.

Comment: I googled a bit and I think there is no such feature for Evince unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, and it appears that `evince` doesn't have a collapse all option. So i found an alternative how to achieve this result. Just open the `pdf` file in `Google Chrome` (maybe it works in `Chromium` too, or `Firefox`, I didn't checked). When Chrome will open your file in top right corner will be a `Bookmarks` button (an icon of a flag) and the menu will be entirely collapsed. Hope it'll help you or other folks that have this problem.

Comment: Sadly opening PDF file with web browser didn't save the last page opened.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 42.3 of it's now possible collapse/expand the entire tree or a single element:

[image]